# Copy words from c-string into 2D array of c-strings

Tags: c++, computer-science, c-strings

So I need to turn a c-string of characters (letters and spaces) into a 2-dimensional array of c-strings.  Each "row" of the 2D array must consist of letters and only letters.  Essentially I need to take the words of a sentence and make an array out of them.

For example: "im upset that on nov th  my  brandnew bmw lis were stolen" should be turned into 2d c-string array like: "im","upset","that","on","nov","th","my","brandnew","bmw","lis","were","stolen".
(*Notice that there are two space characters between "th" and "my" & "my" and "brandnew"*)

The following code gives me some interesting output in my console...

```
char document[201] = "im upset that on nov th  my  brandnew bmw lis were stolen";

char documentArray[13][201];

for (int i, k, j = 0;document[k] != '\0';)
{
    if (isspace(document[k]))
    {
        cout << "found a space" << endl;
        k++;
        while (isspace(document[k]))
        {
            k++;
        }
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
    if (isalpha(document[k]))
    {
        documentArray[i][j] = document[k];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < maxWords +1; i++)
{
    cout << documentArray[i] << endl;
}
```

The output produced has some weird stuff in it.  I don't know what it means (if you could tell me that would be awesome).  Could you please help me solve this issue?

Here's the console output:

```
im\203\377
upset
that
on
nov
th
my\3261
brandnew
bmw_\377
lis
were
stolen\301$r\377
\377
```

Comment: `k` is not initialized, `document[k] != '\0'` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You're right. k isn't explicitly initialized. I believe that it should default to 0 (maybe not reliably though), especially since the output seems to indicate that it is working.

Comment: documentArray must be initialized too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the line with the `j++;` insert the following

```
if (j < 201) {
  documentArray[i][j+1] = '\0'; # terminate the c string
} else {
  documentArray[i][j] = '\0'; # cannot terminate the c string, overwrite the last char to terminate the string
}
```

But please make sure that every read AND write operation NEVER exceeds the array dimensions.

Your array limits are documentArray[0..12][0..200].
Please ALWAYS check that. => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Comment: This question was for a specific part of a project, so the initializer of documentArray[13][201] was intentional, but thank you so much!

Comment: Writing beyond your array dimensions may modify your code, modify variables, doing jumps to somewhere in your program. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a terminating null character to the end of your C strings when copying into the 2D array.

In C string are represented by arrays of characters terminated by a '\0' character. The strange codes you are seeing are likely the result of the '\0' not being encountered and the print running of the end of the character array.